# Using Matplotlib how to plot algebraic equations

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, linear-algebra, mplot3d

Using Matplotlib, how can I plot the following algebraic equations in 3d?
Would like to visualize the intersection of 3-planes.

```
x - y + 2z =  5

    y -  z = -1

         z =  3
```

Comment: It's called *matplotlib* not *mat**h**plotlib* - meaning it does not plot mathematical functions. You will need to compute discrete values of (x, y, z) pairs to plot them. Alternatively, have a look at [sympy's plotting module](http://docs.sympy.org/dev/modules/plotting.html) which may be more akin to what you want to achieve.

Comment: I always thought matplotlib stands for mat**h**ematical plotting library.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest just to clarify, the OP originally spelled matplotlib with h. I rather thought that it was named after Matlab, which is short for *matrix laboratory*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The equations need to be brought in a closed form to be plotted with matplotlib. This is relatively easy for those equations from the question.
One can then use a meshgrid in 2 dimensions to compute the values of the missing dimension according to the equations. Now, having values for all 3 dimensions, we can use a `plot_surface` to plot the planes.

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np


z1 = lambda x,y: 5./2.-x/2.+y/2.    # x - y + 2z =  5
z2 = lambda x,y: y+1                #     y -  z = -1
z3 = lambda x,y: 3.*np.ones_like(x) #          z =  3

x = np.arange(-3,3)
X,Y = np.meshgrid(x,x)


fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
ax.set_xlabel("x"); ax.set_ylabel("y"); ax.set_zlabel("z")


surf = ax.plot_surface(X, Y, z1(X,Y), color="C1", linewidth=0, shade=False)
surf = ax.plot_surface(X, Y, z2(X,Y), color="C2", linewidth=0, shade=False)
surf = ax.plot_surface(X, Y, z3(X,Y), color="C3", linewidth=0, shade=False)


plt.show()
```

[image]

The planes do not seem to intersect, which is due to matplotlib not being a true 3D renderer.

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly I was looking for. Any reason not being a true 3D renderer? I see more complex 3D examples in their gallery.

Comment: The artists in a 3D plot are simply projected onto 2D space. This means that one artist is either in front or behind another, but not partially in front and partially behind. The only way to solve this in matplotlib would be to divide the plane into two sections depending on the viewing angle.

Comment: With %matplotlib notebook and using alpha=0.5 in all plot_surface....eg:. ax.plot_surface(X, Y, z1(X,Y), alpha=0.5, rstride=100, cstride=100), I can change the viewing angle to see the intersection of planes in the Jupyter Notebook and all planes intersect at a point